# How to place Plot Information within a Text box on top of a Bar Chart?

Tags: graphics

How could I place a text box on the top of a bar chart where the top line would have a larger font size than the second line?

My Data:

```
totals4={{1093, "AUSTRALIA"}, {235, "BELGIUM"}, {474, "BERMUDA"}, {187, "BRAZIL"}, {103, "BAHAMAS"}};
```

This code will plot the `PlotLabel->` as a long string. I would like to move " - excludes USA, as of: June 2012" to the second line with a smaller font and not bold. Ideally this text would be within a box, however I would just be happy to get the second line to display correctly.

```
BarChart[#, ChartStyle -> "DarkRainbow", PlotLabel -> 
Style["Entities with LEI Number - excludes USA, as of: June 2012", 
Bold, FontSize -> 12],  
ChartLabels -> (Placed[
Rotate[Style[#, Black], Pi/3] & /@ #2, {{.7, 0}, {1, 1}}])] & @@
Transpose[totals4]
```

[image]

I have tried this code but it is not displaying correctly:

```
BarChart[#, ChartStyle -> "DarkRainbow",
             PlotLabel -> Style[TraditionalForm[Grid[{
    {TextCell[    
         Row[{"Entities with LEI Number (excludes USA)",
        HoldForm[Subscript[a, b]], " As of June 2012"}], 
      TextJustification -> 1], SpanFromLeft},
    }, Frame -> All]
  ], FontFamily ._ "Times"],  
ChartLabels -> (Placed[
  Rotate[Style[#, Black], Pi/3] & /@ #2, {{.7, 0}, {1, 1}}])] & @@
 Transpose[totals4]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try this:

```
BarChart[#, 
ChartStyle -> "DarkRainbow", 
PlotLabel -> Framed[Text[
Grid[{
{Style["Entities with LEI Number", Blue, FontSize -> 18]}, 
{Style["excludes USA, as of: June 2012", Red, FontSize -> 12]}}]]],
ChartLabels -> (Placed[Rotate[Style[#, Black], Pi/3] & /@ #2, {{.7, 0}, {1, 1}}])] & @@
Transpose[totals4]
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
PlotLabel -> Framed[Column[{
    Style["Entities with LEI Number", Bold, FontSize -> 12], 
    Style["excludes USA, as of: June 2012", FontSize -> 10]}]],
```

gives

[image]

This uses the `Column` function to allow two as many `Style` commands as you might wish, and `Framed` makes the frame around the two elements of the columns. You can provide any kind of styling you wish in each of the elements of the column.

Comment: Thanks, Is there a way to change the font and un-bold the second line?